# Amazon Web Services go into sleep mode after inactivity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I’m seeing behavior in my iOS app with uploading images to `Amazon S3` longer first time after some period of inactivity than next uploads. So does `AWS` move bucket into sleep mode after inactivity? I didn’t find any mention about it in the documentation, but I know that `Azure` and `Heroku` use similar sleeping mode

Comment: No, something else it going on - S3 doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: How much of a difference do you see?  The likely explanation involves reuse of a keep-alive connection for subsequent uploads within a few seconds of each other, while the first upload would require connection and TLS session establishment, which requires at least three more round trips compared to a reused connection.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, First upload is about 8 seconds, next about 2 seconds.  and the period between uploads can be 20 minutes. I can even stop my application and run it after 20 minutes and the upload will be fast. Anyway thank you for comments, I will look into what it can be. If you have any guesses I will be glad to hear them